# javascript type checking with reflect

Tags: javascript, reflect

I'm currently using the following to check a variable for type:

```
Object.prototype.toString.call(_value) === '[object String]'
```

but my eslint rules are saying that:
*Avoid using Function.prototype.call, instead use Reflect.apply*

can reflect be used in this way?

Comment: The much more important question is who and why taught you to do that? What are you trying to do? Have you picked that up from a book or some Internet resource? I've not seen that kind of code anywhere. Want to know the type of object? Use `typeof`. `toString` is, as you may have surmised, for default string conversion. And not all string objects will yield `"[object String]"` -- `toString` can be overriden and I can make my `toString` return anything. You have been woefully misinformed here. There is also `instanceof`, among others. Depends on the context, which you do not provide at all.

Comment: Good point.  Thank you for your help, I've used typeof.  I got the original code from somewhere in a blog.

I can't mark your reply as an answer though.